# PHPUnit Xdebug with PhpStorm Breakpoint is not being triggered unless I disable listening button

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug, drupal-8

I have a really strange situation where PhpStorm doesn't seem to catch my breakpoint unless I start the test with the listen button enabled, then after it starts, I then disable the button.

See screen capture below and config files.

Any ideas on what I might have configured incorrectly?

Here's what PhpStorm displays in the console while it's "hung" -

```
Testing started at 12:57 PM ...
/usr/local/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9009 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 /private/var/folders/k7/ckk7n60x31s1h2s_hqcy9h4c0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php --configuration /Users/justinwinter/Sites/drupal85/docroot/core/phpunit.xml --filter "/::testWatchdog( .*)?$/" Drupal\Tests\dblog\Functional\DbLogResourceTest /Users/justinwinter/Sites/drupal85/docroot/core/modules/dblog/tests/src/Functional/DbLogResourceTest.php
PHPUnit 4.8.36 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing Drupal\Tests\dblog\Functional\DbLogResourceTest
```

---

Here's a screengrab gif showing the odd behavior of getting the breakpoint to trigger only after disabling the PhpStorm "Stop Listening for PHP Debug Connections"

[image: PhpStorm PHPUnit Xdebug Issue ScreenGrab Video]

Note, I have a local LAMP stack setup and running great based off this blog post:
https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions

[image: PHPUnit Configuration Setting]

[image: Configuration Environment Variables]

**Xdebug Settings**

```
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => PHPSTORM => PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 1000 => 1000
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /var/tmp/ => /var/tmp/
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => /Users/justinwinter/Desktop/xdebug.log => /Users/justinwinter/Desktop/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9009 => 9009
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /var/tmp/ => /var/tmp/
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => -1 => -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data => -1 => -1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => -1 => -1
```

---

**XDEBUG LOG** (GIST)

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/03a1e6bbf7139e2f860589f09ef1fa8e

Here's one more screenshot from my phpstorm:  Languages & Frameworks > php > Test Frameworks screen

[image: phpstorm Languages & Frameworks php Test Frameworks screen]

---

Here's my `core/phpunit.xml` file which I'm using for my phpunit configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- TODO set checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode="true" once https://www.drupal.org/node/2626832 is resolved. -->
<!-- PHPUnit expects functional tests to be run with either a privileged user
 or your current system user. See core/tests/README.md and
 https://www.drupal.org/node/2116263 for details.
-->
<phpunit bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php" colors="true"
         beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="true"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         beStrictAboutChangesToGlobalState="true"
         checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode="false">
<!-- TODO set printerClass="\Drupal\Tests\Listeners\HtmlOutputPrinter" once
 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24808 is resolved. Drupal provides a
 result printer that links to the html output results for functional tests.
 Unfortunately, this breaks the output of PHPStorm's PHPUnit runner. However, if
 using the command line you can add
 - -printer="\Drupal\Tests\Listeners\HtmlOutputPrinter" to use it (note there
 should be no spaces between the hyphens).
-->
  <php>
    <!-- Set error reporting to E_ALL. -->
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="32767"/>
    <!-- Do not limit the amount of memory tests take to run. -->
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
    <!-- Example SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL value: http://localhost -->
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="http://drupal85.dev"/>
    <!-- Example SIMPLETEST_DB value: mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename#table_prefix -->
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="mysql://root:@localhost/d8"/>
    <!-- Example BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY value: /path/to/webroot/sites/simpletest/browser_output -->
    <env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" value=""/>
    <!-- To disable deprecation testing uncomment the next line. -->
    <!-- <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="disabled"/> -->
    <!-- Example for changing the driver args to mink tests MINK_DRIVER_ARGS value: '["http://127.0.0.1:8510"]' -->
    <!-- Example for changing the driver args to phantomjs tests MINK_DRIVER_ARGS_PHANTOMJS value: '["http://127.0.0.1:8510"]' -->
  </php>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="unit">
      <file>./tests/TestSuites/UnitTestSuite.php</file>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="kernel">
      <file>./tests/TestSuites/KernelTestSuite.php</file>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="functional">
      <file>./tests/TestSuites/FunctionalTestSuite.php</file>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="functional-javascript">
      <file>./tests/TestSuites/FunctionalJavascriptTestSuite.php</file>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <listeners>
    <listener class="\Drupal\Tests\Listeners\DeprecationListener">
    </listener>
    <!-- The Symfony deprecation listener has to come after the Drupal
    deprecation listener -->
    <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener">
    </listener>
    <listener class="\Drupal\Tests\Listeners\DrupalStandardsListener">
    </listener>
    <listener class="\Drupal\Tests\Listeners\DrupalComponentTestListener">
    </listener>
  </listeners>
  <!-- Filter for coverage reports. -->
  <filter>
    <whitelist>
      <directory>./includes</directory>
      <directory>./lib</directory>
      <directory>./modules</directory>
      <directory>../modules</directory>
      <directory>../sites</directory>
      <!-- By definition test classes have no tests. -->
      <exclude>
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./</directory>
        <directory suffix="TestBase.php">./</directory>
      </exclude>
     </whitelist>
  </filter>
</phpunit>
```

**PHPSTORM XDEBUG SETTINGS**

[image: xdebug settings]

---

**DBGp Proxy settings - shouldn't matter though right?**

[image: DBGp Proxy]

---

### **UPDATE:**

Per the comment provided by @lazyone I went ahead and increased the number of simultaneous connections and was able to get PHPStorm to catch the breakpoint correctly. I'm not sure if there is something else going on though or not?

[image: Max simultaneous connections - 3]

Comment: Show your PHPUnit config (just in case). But mainly -- show Xdebug from PhpStorm settings. Ideally would be good to show here xdebug log -- to see what it has to say about it. I have one rather wild guess though. P.S. Not sure about last 3 env variables (from 2nd/3rd screenshot) - I do not think they will be applied this way (port and host must have been written correctly already in actual php.ini; the connect_back option does not seem to play any role here (as your xdebug settings (last list) shows that it's "on") -- but maybe it's because it was taken differently.

Comment: @LazyOne I added a gist for my xdebug log and added one more screen grab of my PHPStorm "Test Frameworks screen" . I'll also add my `phpunit.xml` file as well.

Comment: I've asked for a Xdebug settings screen from PhpStorm. PHPUnit config is OK (have not found possibly problematic option there).

Comment: @LazyOne Sorry about that - I think I've attached the only other XDebug Settings screens I know of above. Last two screen shots. Thanks for taking a look at this!

Comment: OK -- you have added it now. Please increase the number of simultaneous xdebug connections from default 1 to 2 or even 3. You seem to be having subrequest going on .. which runs as separate request/debug session and IDE cannot accept it until the limit is full -- so when you click that "stop listening" button it breaks the connection so another one can be worked with. That's how I interpret the xdebug log -- you have 2nd session started in the middle of first one and it gets closed only after 2nd is closed.

Comment: Looking closely now (have not noticed it straight away because of poor image quality) -- even your GIF shows that you have 2 debug tabs (it jumps to 2nd `stdin` after you click to "stop listening"); with single debug session you should have only 1 tab AFAIK.

Comment: BTW -- my "P.S." form first comment still stands -- the `remote_connect_back` you are passing that way does not make any difference (is not doing what you were hoped for) -- xdebug clearly shows that xdebug still tries to guess the IP, but since it's a CLI request it obviously does not find any HTTP headers and uses `localhost` instead). No idea where you took that passing the config that way will work (have not checked the links you gave though, maybe it was there)

Comment: Wow - ok, increasing the number of simultaneous xdebug connections to 3 does in fact catch the breakpoint now! Any ideas why there is this `stdin` sub request going on? Is that normal? I also went ahead and removed the `remote_connect_back`

Comment: I have no idea about your code -- actual code and what your test does. But you definitely have some sort of sub-request (be it in Drupal core, some library used before reaching your breakpoint or whatever) -- it could be the way how you test it. I suggest placing breakpoint in actual test and dig from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please increase number of **max simultaneous debug connections** in PhpStorm settings -- by default it's only 1 .. and based on the xdebug log (and after re-checking the pretty poor quality gif animation again) you seem to have some sort of sub-request going on .. which requires separate debug connection ... which IDE cannot accept as it's already reached the limit (of 1). By clicking "stop listening" the first connection is released so IDE can accept 2nd one.

Quite likely it's because of the way how your test code gets executed (PHPUnit settings, for example, although I have not noticed the expected in such case option in PHPUnit config file).